# Add an attribute name as parameter - QGIS 3 modeler

Tags: qgis-3, fields-attributes, qgis-modeler, parameters

I'd like make a model where I can change an attribute name to a predefined one using refact tool. How can I get that "attribute" by a parameter from a vectoral field ? 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

In this case you will need one step before this.

Add a Field Calculator that receives a string input in the name of the new field.
Change the Result Field Name option to Use Model Input.
[image: Example]

The refactor fields do not receive singular parameters as input.

Comment: Thats what I did, thanks. But I still think that something could be done....